# Let $p(x)$ be polynomial over $GF(2)$ with $deg(p(x))=8$, show that $g(x)\nmid x^{31}-1$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be polynomial over $GF(2)$ with $\operatorname{deg}(p(x))=8$, show that $p(x)\nmid x^{31}-1$

I know that $x^{2^5}-x=x^{32}-x=x(x^{31}-1)$ is a product of all monic irreducible polynomials of degree dividing 5 (actually the minimal polynomials over the field $GF(2)$). Meaning that over $GF(2)$ it is a product of only the irreducible polynomial with degree 5 and 1 when only $x$ and $x-1$ are the polynomials with degree 1. Now, it means the $x^{31}-1$ is a product of the irreducible polynomial with degree 5 and $x-1$. now assume to the contrary that $p(x)|x^{31}-1$. It means that p(x) is the product of some of the irreducible polynomials with degree 5 and $x-1$ (**this is the part I'm not sure about**), but it can't be since not any combination of the irreducible polynomials will give polynomial with $\deg(p(x))=8$.

As I mentioned I'm not absolutely sure about my conclusion. I know there is some other information that might be helpful, and I tried to proceed with the following :

Since $gcd(31,2)=1$ then is also known that $p(x)$ has only simple roots in its extension field. I know that the extension field of  $x^{2^5}-x$ is $GF(2^5)$, and the roots of the irreducible polynomials (the minimal polynomials) are the groups of the conjugates (each polynomial has a group of 5/1 conjugates that are the roots of it). Now if I could say that roots of $p(x)$ in its extension field are also roots of $x^{31}-1$ since we assumed $p(x)|x^{31}-1$ (**but I don't as I don't know the connection between $p(x)$ extension field and the extension field of $x^{31}-1$**). So if I could say that, then because of the fact that the conjugates of the roots are also roots it must be that $p(x)$ have more roots than 8 (it implies from a theorem that says that if polynomial over a small field has root in the extension field, all of the conjugates are also roots).

Comment: We have $x^{32}-1=(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1)
(x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x^5 + x^3 + 1)(x^5 + x^2 + 1)(x + 1)$ by using Berlkamp's algorithm. So only degree $5$, except for $x-1$.

Comment: You probably meant $x^{31}-1$. I don't familiar with Berlkamp's algorithm. so it does not enough the say that  $x^{31}-1$ is a product of only irreducible polynomial with degree 5 and $x−1$ as I explained? since I don't really understand the difference between what you say to this. Moreover, how this solve my doubt about my conclusion saying "It means that p(x) is the product of some of the irreducible polynomials with degree 5 and $x−1$"? Thank you

Comment: I mean saying "It means that p(x) is the product of some of the irreducible polynomials with degree 5 and $x−1$" seems straightforward but I want to be 100% sure that I don't miss something.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I meant $x^{31}-1$. You can be sure that there is no factor of degree $8$. Of course, you can show this with different (and easier) arguments.

Comment: I think the argument Dietrich gave is the easiest way. Of course, we won't need the actual factorization of $x^{31}-1$ to see that it has a single linear factor and six factors of degree five. This follows from the result, true for all $m$, that in $GF(2)[x]$
$$x^{2^m}-x=\prod p(x),$$ where the product is over **all** the (monic) irreducible polynomials $p(x)$ such that $\deg p(x)\mid m$. Here $m=5$, so $\deg p(x)$ can only be $1$ or $5$. Other than $x$ and $x+1$ the other factors must all have degree $5$.

Comment: Re: your question. Consider the following. There are $31$ elements in the multiplicative group of $GF(2^5)$. By Lagrange's theorem (from the first course on groups) the order of any element o$\alpha$ of the multiplicative group must be a factor of $31$. Therefore $\alpha^{31}=1$ and hence $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^{31}-1$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is a factor of $x^{31}-1$. More or less proving the theorem from the previous comment in this case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The first comment was my first argument. Thank you for confirming